# div box doesn't align under other divs

Tags: html, css

The footer div doesn't align under other divs but looks like it's as heigh as the content div. (visible between the content and the sidebar div)

What is the solution for this? (And what was the problem, I want to know that too)

```
#container{
    width:1200px;
    margin:10px auto;
}

#content{
    width:65%;
    min-height:350px;
    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    background-color:#f6904e;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar{
    width:410px;
    min-height:350px;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    background-color:#fddc68;
    float:right;
}


#footer{
    margin-top:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#de3643;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HwM8M/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the float.

Explanation: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Another useful link: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/HwM8M/1/

HTML:

```
    <br class="clear" />
```

add css:

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` in `#footer`:

```
#footer{
    margin-top:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#de3643;
    display:inline-block;/*Add this*/
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwM8M/2/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `#footer` css:

```
clear: both;
```

Edited js:

http://jsfiddle.net/HwM8M/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
<div id="footer">
     Wouter Schaeffer
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HwM8M/3/)